# Running classes from Java GUI

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, testing

How can you execute a test XML file from a Java GUI.

For example in the GUI you have a text box which you provide the path the XML file, and then press a run button. The code inside the run button will then execute what ever XML file that you have provided the path to.

Comment: a) How do you "run" a XML-File? b) How is this related to running java classes? c) [**"theology"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theology) - wtf??

Comment: @Fildor a) In automated testing you specify your tests in an XML file and run this file to run your tests b) Since some people might not be aware of automated testing I presumed the same theory behind running a java class would be the same, the code just exectues what ever it is pointing to. C) that was a big spelling mistake , was meant to be " theory "

Comment: OK, so you are talking about configuration-xml for automated testing. That was not at all clear. What's your Test Engine? Should be possible all in all.

Comment: @Fildor I'm using TestNG. I have all the automation side done. At the moment I'm using Jenkins to run my code from GITHUB. What I want now is to create my own GUI that I can use to type in the path of my XMLs and then press a run button that will execute the code.

Comment: @colin Running a Java class and executing tests based on XML files are completely different beasts. There aren't many things that are completely impossible when dealing with programming, so this is really a poor question. The big question is "Is this something that's possible for you to achieve with your current skillset" (assuming you'll be widening your skillset while working on the project).

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks, I can see now where my question was weak. I just presumed that the code would just be the same. As the goal of the code is to execute whatever its told to execute. This is something I'm not familiar with and with coding I'm not that strong and when it comes to explaining stuff, as you can see I'm a bit poor. That's why I like to do these projects to get an idea of all aspects.

Comment: @Kayaman I have edited my question, hopefully for the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was established earlier, you can't "run" XML files. They're structured data that by themselves don't do anything. However you mentioned TestNG, so I'll assume the XML files are parseable by TestNG.

You'll need to integrate TestNG with your program and implement a basic filechooser to retrieve the path of the XML file, passing it to TestNG and letting it do what it does. Perfectly doable I'd imagine, although I'm not familiar with TestNG API.

No need to even bother with custom classloaders.

Comment: Thank you, I'm starting to understand more. That makes sense when you talk about TestNG parsing the XML.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand you correctly, you want to implement your own test framework and want to know how to call methods, create objects from a different projects class files.

This is possible using Javas reflection API. First, you have to call the class loader:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
String testClassName = "my.example.TestClass"; 
Class testClass = classLoader.loadClass(testClassName);
```

Afterwards, you can call "newInstance()" to create an object of your previously loaded class. The method "getMethod()" can be used to get a Method object which can be invoked using "invoke()".

You can find alot information about reflection API on google and stackoverflow too. First hit on google is for example:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-dynamic-class-loading-java-reflection-api/

Comment: I have updated my question just as you answered as people where getting confused. I'm not familiar with this so I dunno if your answer is suitable or not but I will have a look into it, thank you.